# c++ std::vector.insert crashes on debug but works on release

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, iterator

My program crashes on this line but only in debug build, it works fine in release build.

```
m_lstIds.insert(m_lstIds.begin() + indexInsert, ID);
```

'm_lstIds' is a std::vector of int, 'ID' is an int. When the program crashed, m_lstIds had 3 items (1, 2, 3). indexInsert was '0' and ID was '0'.

The error message says:

```
Expression: vector iterator + offset out of range
```

I am running visual studio 2010; I am guessing it has something to do with bad project settings which conflicted with STL optimization.

**Edit:**
When I said: "works on release" I meant if I do `std::cout<<m_lstIds[i]` for i = 0..3, I will actually get 0,1,2,3 printed out. In debug build it just crashes when I try to insert.

**Edit2:**
I found the answer! Thanks everyone for the help.

Here is the shortest repro. The problem is the `memset` function I call at the constructor. Because the constructor of `m_lstItem` was called before the `memset`, it will erase whatever data in the vector that allowed `insert` to work properly.

What's really interesting is how this worked in release but not in debug. Would be great if someone can explain that part.

```
struct SimpleList
{
  SimpleList()
  {
    memset(this, 0, sizeof(SimpleList));
    m_lstItem.push_back(0);
    m_lstItem.push_back(1);
    m_lstItem.push_back(2);
  }

  void Crash()
  {
    m_lstItem.insert(m_lstItem.begin() + 0, 3);
  }

  std::vector<int>m_lstItem;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{ 
  SimpleList sl;
  sl.Crash();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure that the container has three elements and that the index was 0?  The fact that it "works" in release implies that the code is actually broken, but without the runtime checks you don't get any errors.

Comment: Show us a working example of your code, it's tough for us to figure out how the vector is modified, used, etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Will need to see the full code.

Comment: I can reproduce only if ( begin() + insertIndex ) *is* out of bounds. That results in failure regardless of build target.

Comment: Is this just a single project, or do you have multiple projects in your solution?

Comment: I believe you're not initializing a variable which is set to 0 in the release version and 0xcdcdcdcd in the debug version or some other garbage, which ends up referencing an invalid index. This would be possible if you don't initialize the "i" variable properly (with a 0). Ahh no, sorry, you said at insert.. well you could check those too :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the ideas! I am trying everything right now to get a minimum repro, but whenever I move that code elsewhere it works again... I know I am getting closer to the answer.

Comment: `memset(this, 0, sizeof(SimpleList));` DON'T do this unless your class is POD !! `std::vector` MUST be initialized with its own constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memset(this, 0, sizeof(SimpleList));` is unsafe when your struct is **not a POD**.

Due to the member `std::vector<int>m_lstItem;`, your struct is not a POD.

Therefor, using `memset` is **unsafe** in this case, and leads to *undefined behaviour*. In other words: anything is allowed to happen! And *anything* includes working as expected...

My advice: Do not use `memset` in C++ unless you totally know what you are doing.

Comment: That does answer my question, but your answer was posted after I found the problem myself :-)

Comment: @Twelvethousand It was posted after you posted the full code. Any expert would have pointed at the memset within seconds after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the indexInsert is not 0 when the programe running.
And the vector will throw exception when the vector out of range in DEBUG mode,and in RELEASE mode it won't.
So show you full code.

Comment: you are right, cannot memset struct which contain STL variable;I made the mistake before as you are :-)