# Application crashes on std::vector::insert

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, crash

My application is crashing at the following line in an application that I am working on:

```
struct PointIndex
{
  int PointNr;
};
struct PointIndex PI = { 0 };
std::vector<PointIndex> MyVec;
MyVec.insert( MyVec.begin(), PI );
```

The code as shown is considerably simplified (e.g., `MyVec` is really a member of a C data structure that until recently was a POD, but some pointers within it were changed to vectors to appease Coverity), but the application I am working is quite large and right now, I would appreciate some hints on what could be wrong.

Visual Studio 2010 shows this as the call stack:

```
MyAppl.dll!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > >::operator+=(int _Off=-1)  Line 157 + 0x15 bytes   C++
MyAppl.dll!std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > >::operator+=(int _Off=-1)  Line 359  C++
MyAppl.dll!std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > >::operator-=(int _Off=1)  Line 371   C++
MyAppl.dll!std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > >::operator-(int _Off=1)  Line 376 + 0xc bytes    C++
MyAppl.dll!std::vector<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> >::emplace<PointIndex &>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > > _Where={PointNr=??? }, PointIndex & _Val={...})  Line 689 + 0x4a bytes C++
MyAppl.dll!std::vector<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> >::insert<PointIndex &>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<PointIndex,std::allocator<PointIndex> > > _Where={PointNr=??? }, PointIndex & _Val={...})  Line 675 + 0x3b bytes  C++
```

The vector is empty at the time of crash, but from what I see, `begin` should be identical to `end` for empty vectors and `insert` with the `end` iterator is same as `push_back`.

I looked around for anyone who faced a similar issue, and the closest I could find was [c++ std::vector.insert crashes on debug but works on release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336460/), and I have checked the entire solution for calls to `memset` and didn't find any pertinent to this library.

Any/all insights gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I believe your code is *too* simplified. Probably you hit undefined behavior before the insertion, but the bug manifests itself only there. I'm afraid without context it will be impossible for us to solve your problem

Comment: How are you allocating the "C data structure"?

Comment: Given that this is the *first* insert into an empty vector, we know that it will need a memory allocation: crystal ball tells me that have corrupted your heap beforehand.

Comment: Try writing a single piece of code that people can take, compile, and experience the same behaviour (i.e. the crash).

Comment: You're not including anything that would #define PI somewhere, would you? Assuming that this is the real code, simplified.

Comment: Thanks to all who've responded thus far.  I am quite familiar with the concept of UB and how it could get demons to fly out of my nose.  In this instance, it is crashing at the same point consistently -- thank you for (*implicitly*) telling me that there isn't anything in the way I am calling insert that could cause it to fail.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson -- I am calling `MyCStruct *myVal = new MyCStruct();` (yes, with the open-close parenthesis) where `MyVec` is now a member of `MyCStruct`.  I find that VS 2010 does not zero out the other members of MyCStruct.

Comment: @TimoGeusch -- Good guess, but no cigar.  I suppose had a `#define` been in effect, the compilation would have failed.

Comment: Does the `_Off` variable/parameter/argument value in the various calls within the STL implementation shed any light on what is the problem?  Or since the general consensus is that it is UB, it *must* have happened somewhere upstream?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a dynamic linkage (e.g. /MD) or a static linkage (e.g. /MT)? When you have the memory operations in both dll & application(e.g. allocate a memory in the dll and delete it in the application), both of them should be compiled with the dynamic linkage.
To change the linkage, goto the Property Page - Code Generation - Runtime library